Not able to authorize ROLE based Spring boot
Whenever trying to access the ROLE authorized links the Response is same
{
    "timestamp": "2024-11-05T20:40:04.760+00:00",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "path": "/user/dashboard"
}

This is my Entity which implements the UserDetails and here the Role i have created is an ENUM : USER, ADMIN which is then set in the Arraylist
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {
    ...
    @NotNull(message = "Roles are required")
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
} 

This is my config where I am trying to authorize the endpoints via role based authorization and /user is only accessible by USER role users
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    return httpSecurity
        .csrf(customizer -> customizer.disable())
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> {
                    authorize.requestMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER");
                    authorize.requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
                    authorize.anyRequest().permitAll();
        })
        .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .sessionManagement(session ->                         session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .build();
}

This is the controller for user
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    public ResponseEntity<String> dashboard() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Dashboard");
    }
}

How can I make sure that ROLE based authorization works.

Show the logic that adds the roles to your roles collection

Override when inheriting UserDetails from Entity
    private Role role;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.name()));
    }

You need to override the following method
Also, I don't think it's a good idea to delegate responsibility for managing authentication object information used in SpringSecurity to an entity.
How about creating authDetails etc like this:
class AuthDetails(
    val member: Member,
) : UserDetails {

    override fun getAuthorities(): MutableCollection<out GrantedAuthority>? = member.roles

    override fun getPassword(): String? = null

    override fun getUsername(): String = member.email

    override fun isAccountNonExpired(): Boolean = true

    override fun isAccountNonLocked(): Boolean = true

    override fun isCredentialsNonExpired(): Boolean = true

    override fun isEnabled(): Boolean = true
}

Also you need to configure the service to ovveride loadByUsername of UserDetailsService
